# React setState does not update state even in useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

So I am making a salary counter that updates every second. I have a setInterval timer set up in the useEffect hook to update my "currentSalary" using setState, the value of "currentSalary" keeps updating just fine but when I log the value it is always 0. I can't wrap my head around this. Never had a problem setting state before.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
 function App() {
  //State
  const [date, setDate] = useState();
  const [salaryPerHour] = useState(145);
  const [salaryPerSecond] = useState(salaryPerHour / 60 / 60);
  const initialSalary = 0;
  const [currentSalary, setCurrentSalary] = useState(initialSalary);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Use effect att App.js");
    if (!date) {
      setInterval(function() {
        updateDate();
        setCurrentSalary(prevCurrentSalary => prevCurrentSalary + salaryPerSecond);
        console.log(currentSalary);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

Comment: The state update using the updater provided by useState hook is asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of logging the value in that useEffect hook, you can try creating another useEffect hook that is run whenever an update is made to the state `currentSalary`

The hook would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(currentSalary)
}, [currentSalary])
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentSalary` is a local const. It will never change, and that's not what `setCurrentSalary` is trying to do. Instead, the purpose of calling `setCurrentSalary` is to tell react to rerender the component. On that next render a new local variable will be created, and it will get the new value. But the log statement from the previous render cannot see this.

So it's updating the value, you just have your log statement in a place where it's not useful. If you'd like to verify that the component is rerendering with a new value, put your log statement in the body of the component.

```
const [currentSalary, setCurrentSalary] = useState(initialSalary);
console.log('rendering with', currentSalary);

useEffect(() => {
  // ...
```